# How to find out if numbers are different in pascal?

Tags: numbers, pascal

i can't solve one pascal problem, first i have to enter N which is the number or mesurments, next i enter those mesurments (if N is 5 i enter 5 mesurments for exmaple 3 4 5 6 7). After that i enter Q which is the number of times i check the number of different numbers in a specific part of the row. For example you have input
5 (number of mesurments)
1 2 3 3 4 (mesurments)
3 (number of checkings)
1 3
3 4
1 5 (left number is the starting number from the row, if it's 1 you start from 1, if it's 4 you start from 3 because 3 is the fourth mesurment and the right number is the last number if it's 5 it would be 4 because 4 is the fifth in the row)

And for output you would get 
3
1
4 (for the first checking you have number from 1 to 3 (1 2 3) and you have 3 different numbers, second mesurment from 3 to 4 (3 3) and it's 1 different number and last from 1 to 5 there are 4 different numbers)

Hope you understod me, and thanks if you can solve it, i am in highschool now and i am preparing my self for something more complicating :) thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a great place to get help with homework *if* you explain what you've tried so far, where exactly you're getting stuck, and what kind of help you're looking for.

Comment: Well i am stuck at the beginning, how do i make it if i don't know the exact number of varialbes, when i know i have 2 for example i can put read(x,y) and when i have N number of variables what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

The inequality operator of Pascal is <>

Comment: yes, but what confuses me is how to i make an unspecific number of variabler, i mean when i know i have 2 mesurments i can make it read(x,y) for example, but when i have N number of variables, how do i make it? i know how to find out if 2 numbers are unequal

Comment: This is highly dependent on the Pascal dialect and version. Best to look for clues in handout or other suggested reading materials